# why I getting runtime error creating shader type 35663

Tags: c, opengl, shader

I want to learn OpenGL and I follow this [tutorial](http://ogldev.atspace.co.uk/), then on tutorial 1.3 the problem arises. The objective is to make a triangle, but I got an error. the code was compiled but when it runs always get an error creating shader type.

```cpp
/*
Tutorial 03 - First triangle
*/
#include <stdio.h>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/freeglut.h>
#include "math_3d.h"

GLuint VBO;

static void RenderSceneCB()
{
  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
  glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
  glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
  glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
  glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
  glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
  glutSwapBuffers();
}

static void InitializeGlutCallbacks()
{
  glutDisplayFunc(RenderSceneCB);
}

static void CreateVertexBuffer() {
  Vector3f Vertices[3];
  Vertices[0] = Vector3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f);
  Vertices[1] = Vector3f(1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f);
  Vertices[2] = Vector3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

  glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);
  glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
  glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(Vertices), Vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
}


int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  glutInit(&argc, argv);
  glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE|GLUT_RGBA);
  glutInitWindowSize(1024, 768);
  glutInitWindowPosition(100, 100);
  glutCreateWindow("Tutorial 03");

  InitializeGlutCallbacks();

  // Must be done after glut is initialized!
  GLenum res = glewInit();
  if (res != GLEW_OK) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: '%s'\n", glewGetErrorString(res));
    return 1;
  }
  glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
  CreateVertexBuffer();
  glutMainLoop();
  return 0;
}
```

Thanks to [@kilon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/453642/kilon) that remind me, Is it possible because I use windows? The problem is windows related?

Pointing to resources is appreciated

[image: error msg]
[error msg in new tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uf1C6.gif%22error%20msg%22)

Comment: you will need to also paste the error message to make this a proper question

Answer (score 0):

if you use .vsh and .fsh files, try add it to your project:

```
Go to your project -> Targets -> Build Phases -> Copy Bundle Recourses
```

and add this two files.

Hope this help.

UPD: this work for Mac OS (Xcode).